# How to exit from ":!python" in Vim?

Tags: python, shell, vim

I have typed ":!python" to launch python shell in vim, but I can't close it.
I have tried ^Z but it has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^D` is what you are actually looking for.
Alternatively, you can use the expression `exit()` or `quit()`.